# Computing house edge of Lunar New Year dice game

Tags: probability, dice

Here is an apt description of the game: https://medium.com/@Rob_TactVP/how-to-play-hoo-hey-how-812532d405a1

I’ll repeat the rules of the game here.

> Traditionally, Hoo Hey How uses the
> following pay table:
>
> - 1:1 for one matching symbol.
> - 2:1 for two matching symbols.
> - 3:1 for three matching symbols.
> - 30:1 for any triple.
>
> For example: Betting \$5 on "Fish" and having one fish symbol turn up nets \$10 (your initial \$5, plus \$5 in winnings).
> Betting \$5 on "Fish" and having it appear on two dice,
> returns \$15 (your \$5 wager and \$10 in winnings). Three symbols pays
> \$20 (your \$5 bet and \$15 profit). However, you're also allowed to
> wager on a "Triple" option. This pays out at 30 to one, making it look
> like an enticing option. It's not. The odds of all three dice
> displaying the same symbol are very slim.

I wanted first to evaluate the expected value of betting on any of the 6 symbol choices, and ignore the Triple bet for now.

I came up with an expected value of \$0.875 for an investment of \$1, which is alarmingly low and significantly worse than the supposed 8% house advantage that I have been reading about (including from this article).

So let me walk you through the logic that I used to calculate this.

First, the probability of getting all 3 dice matching your chosen symbol:
$(1/6)^3 = 1/216$

Second, the probability of getting exactly 2 dice matching your chosen symbol:
$(1/6)^2 (5/6) = 5/216$

Third, the probability of getting exactly 1 die matching your chosen symbol which I derived by first finding the probability of at least 1 die matching, which should be:
$1 - (5/6)^3$

This is the inverse of the probability of all 3 dice not matching (each with a 5/6 chance of that).

Therefore the probability of exactly 1 die matching should be:

$1 - (\frac{5}{6})^3 - \frac{5}{216} - \frac{1}{216} = 1 - \frac{125 + 6}{216} = \frac{216 - 131}{216} = \frac{85}{216}$

And the expected value calculation:

\$1 invested yields $\$4\frac{1}{216} + \$3\frac{5}{216} + \$2\frac{85}{216} = \$\frac{4 + 15 + 170}{216} = \$\frac{189}{216} = \$\frac{7}{8} = \$0.875$

Have I neglected to consider something in this analysis? I avoided counting the cases out but it would not be too difficult to do this.

Based on this, a player should be losing around \$12.50 per \$100 spent, not \$8. I wonder if it’s just a simple mistranslation where a 1/8 loss got interpreted as an 8% loss.

Let’s revisit the 30:1 for triple. If I interpret this description literally, that’d be 31/36 * \$1 expected value, 0.861111, which is remarkably consistent with (and actually a smidge lower than) 0.875 which is a hint to me that it may actually be correct. This means the expected value is not going to change a whole lot whether the player bets more on individual symbols or on the triple.

Comment: I hope to use my analysis as a starting point for designing a less unfair (and much more exciting!) pay table. It may be possible to have it pay something like 10:1 on hitting all 3 dice!

Comment: In my experience, when we have people over and play this, it is not at all apparent that the house has such a massive advantage. These calculations have surprised me to the point where I’m not sure I did the math right. At one point I felt some intuition that 2 dice could pay 3:1 instead of 2:1 and maybe getting all 3 could pay 7:1. But even that would still be a significant house advantage.

Comment: OK. I think I see where my logic is wrong. I didn’t choose properly. There are 5 ways for the first two dice to yield two matches but I need the rest of the combinations as well.

Answer (score 1):

This showed up in my Google searches and I couldn't find where the 8% was originally calculated but hopefully the below will make sense.

Ignoring the triple bet, the expected value of this game can be calculated as follows.

Let us assume $1 is bet on fish. The expected value of the bet is:

$\text{EV = (Probability of Winning $\times$ Amount Won Per Bet) $-$ (Probability of Losing $\times$ Amount Lost Per Bet)}$

There are 4 outcomes possible when betting on fish:

- One fish appearing (\$1 Payout): $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times 3$
- Two fish appearing (\$2 Payout): $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times 3$
- Three fish appearing (\$3 Payout): $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}$
- No fish appearing (\$1 Loss): $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6}$

The expected value can be then calculated:
$\text{EV} = (\frac{25}{72} \times \$ 1 + \frac{5}{72} \times \$2 + \frac{1}{216} \times \$ 3) - (\frac{125}{216} \times \$ 1) = \ \sim-\$0.0787$

With that being said, don't take advantage of those around you with this information.

Comment: Nice! Could you elaborate on why the one fish and two fish cases have an $\times 3$ associated with them? 3 choose 1 and 3 choose 2, right?

Comment: seems like this is where i messed up with my calculation: I missed those two $\times 3$

Comment: For one fish appearing, essentially the fish dice can appear on the first dice, second dice or third dice. Similarly, for two fish appearing, the non fish dice can appear in three different positions. $\times 3$ is just a simplification of summing the same odds three times.